# JMeter 500 error code when running a thread for 50 users

Tags: jmeter

When I run a thread of 1 to 10 users, my script runs fine, but when I add 50 users I get 500 error for atleast 10 threads. I have added HTTP cookie manager.{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException","StackTrace":"   at CommerceEngine.BLL.Services.Orders.ConfirmService.ProcessPayment(List`1 carts, OrderConfigurationModel orderConfig) in C:\\CookieDelivery_OnlineOrdering\\CookieDelivery_CommerceEngine\\BLL\\Services\\Orders\\ConfirmService.cs:line 221\r\n   at CookieService.Business.OrderBusiness.Place(OrderModel orderModel) in C:\\CookieDelivery_OnlineOrdering\\CookieService\\Business\\OrderBusiness.cs:line 460\r\n   at CookieService.Controllers.OrderController.Place(ValidationResultModel`1 order) in C:\CookieDelivery_OnlineOrdering\CookieService\Controllers\OrderController.cs:line 125\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The wait operation timed out","ExceptionType":"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception","StackTrace":null}}

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 3454
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:0940d14d-c861-4eac-a08b-9d4139693e70
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Request-Context
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS
Date: Wed, 10 Nov 2021 17:35:55 GMT

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u8yQ.png)
Please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding`  - the error message clearly indicates that your application attempts to connect to the database to process a payment and doesn't get the response in a timely fashion.

If it doesn't occur for 10 users and occurs for 50 - it's definitely connected with the sad fact that your application gets overloaded and cannot operate normally. By the way, your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) setup doesn't necessarily mean that you have 50 concurrent users, see [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article for more explanation, you can see the actual concurrency using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) chart.

Coming back to your question (although I fail to see how we can "help you to resolve it") - you can inspect your application configuration, especially [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) settings, inspect database logs including the [slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html), use a [profiler tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2022) to see where your application spends the majority of time, check whether your application has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, etc.